# NSTimer not firing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsdate, nstimer

I have an NSTimer that I init with this code:

```
testTimer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:[new objectAtIndex:0] interval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(works:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

`[new objectAtIndex:0]` is an NSDate in the past.

When I start up the app, the timer is getting created, with a fireDate of immediately (since the date is in the past), however it never calls my works method. (`-(void)works:(id)sender`
)

Anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: whether it is wrong to use iphone tag in this question?

Comment: Matt, you can use the [osx] tag to help fend off the hordes of iOS retaggers. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will have to add it to the current run loop if you use `initWith..` method to create the timer object.

```
NSRunLoop * theRunLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[theRunLoop addTimer:testTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Or if you would like it set up for you, use the `scheduled...` methods to create your timer.

Comment: @Matt: it should be noted that using `alloc`/`init` means that you own the timer and need to manage its memory, whereas the `scheduledTimer...` methods return a timer that you do _not_ own. It is retained by the run loop in either case.

Comment: @Josh They are good tips. @Matt To be a bit specific about run loop retaining the timer, it happens when you use `addTimer:forMode:` method. Like mentioned, `scheduledTimer...` methods do that for you so as a result, the run loop retains the timer. When you `invalidate` the timer, the run loop releases the timer.

Comment: You're right, Deepak, I should have made it clearer that `addTimer:...` is what causes the run loop to retain the timer. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

I just recently had an issue with NSTimer. In my case I didn't realize that the method scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval is not multi thread safe. Once I moved the timer to the main thread it started working.

Comment: How, may I ask, did you do that?  I'm having an issue with it firing seemingly randomly.

Comment: try wrapping your nstimer in this:     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    });

Answer (score 3):

I think I had the same problem as Dobler, but my solution was different.

The problem was that the timer was being created and scheduled in a GCD thread in a block within a

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{})
```

call (actually nested deep, so it wasn't obvious that this was the case).

Using `NSTimer's scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:...` placed the timer into an invalid run loop.

The fix was to change to

```
timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(...) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```